# Using unspecified constants in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve a system of equations in the s-domain. So set up this system of equations in matrix form:

```
a=[.4*s+s+5 -5; -5 .5*s+5]  
c=[3/s; 3/(2*s)]  
(1/s)*a*b=c
```

I just get the error that s is undefined.
How can I solve for b in terms of s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab does not (naturally) do symbolic calculations --- which is what your code is trying to do. Matlab's variables need to be concrete numbers, or arrays, or structures, etc. They cannot just be placeholders for arbitrary numbers.

(UNLESS: You use the [symbolic computing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) for Matlab. I haven't really used this because I prefer to do symbolic computing in environments such as Maple or Mathematica. You could even solve your problem on the Wolfram Alpha website)

But if you pick a specific value of s, computing what you want is easy:

```
s = 5;
a=[.4*s+s+5 -5; -5 .5*s+5];
c=[3/s; 3/(2*s)];
b = s*(a\c);
```

Where I have used the [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) for doing linear inversion.

You should now have that

```
(1/s)*a*b-c
```

is the zero vector.

**EDIT:** I looked into the symbolic toolbox. It looks like this is what you want (but you need to have the symbolic toolbox licensed and installed for it to work):

```
syms s;
a=[.4*s+s+5 -5; -5 .5*s+5];
c=[3/s; 3/(2*s)];
b = simple(s*(a\c))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code to perform your calculation using symbolic operators is:

```
syms s;                           %This defines 's' as a symbolic token
a=[.4*s+s+5 -5; -5 .5*s+5];       %a and c inherit the symbolic properties from s
c=[3/s; 3/(2*s)];                 
result = solve('(1/s)*a*b=c','b') %Solve is the general symbolic toolbox algebraic solver.
```

This produces

```
result =
(c*s)/a
```

Generally speaking, Matlab performs best as a numerical toolbox.  So depending on your application I would go with another approach, such as that demonstrated by Ian Hincks in another answer.  But sometimes the situation demands a symbolic solution.